# Language Model through Whoosh in Information Retrieval

Tags: python, information-retrieval, whoosh

I am working in IR.

Can any one guide me, how can I implement the language model in `Whoosh`.
I already Applied TD-IDF and BM25. I am new to IR.

For an example, the simplest form of language model simply throws away all conditioning context, and estimates each term independently. Such a model is called a unigram language model:

```
P_{uni}(t_1t_2t_3t_4) = P(t_1)P(t_2)P(t_3)P(t_4)
```

There are many more complex kinds of language models, such as bigram language models, which condition on the previous term,

```
P_{bi}(t_1t_2t_3t_4) = P(t_1)P(t_2\vert t_1)P(t_3\vert t_2)P(t_4\vert t_3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Whoosh's scoring module](https://github.com/whoosh-community/whoosh/blob/master/src/whoosh/scoring.py) and use BM25F (lines 276 to 332) as a reference for building your own weighting and scoring models. You need to create a Weighting Model and a Scorer. Assuming you want to call your model `Unigram`, the main steps would be:

1. Implement your own `Unigram` weighting model class and inherit from `scoring.WeightingModel`:

   `class Unigram(WeightingModel)`

   Implement the methods required by the base class, the main one being `scorer()`, which returns a reference to your `Scorer` class (next). This class is called when you create your `searcher` and defines the Weighting Model the searcher will use.
2. Implement a `UnigramScorer` class and inherit from `scoring.WeightLengthScorer`:

   `class UnigramScorer(WeightLengthScorer)`

   Implement the `__init__` and `_score` methods. `__init__`  takes the field name and value and is called once for each term in your query when you call `searcher.search()`.
   `_score` is called for each matching document in your results. It takes a `weight` and `length` and returns a score for a given field.
3. When you create your searcher at search time, specify your custom language model using the `weighting` parameter:

   `ix.searcher(weighting = Unigram)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Do you know any other python IR Library which can implement language modal?

Comment: Not off-hand, no.